# Can I have two UITableView objects in a single page for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My app is a portrait app, and I need to put two UITableView objects in a single page, one on the left column, the other one on the right column.

Just like the split view in landscape mode in iPad, I want to reproduce it in portrait mode.

Do I need to configure two data sources and two delegates?

[image]

Comment: Ya you can use any number of tables in one view ,set tags to that tables in Xib put conditions in all delegate and datasource methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have two tableViews and you dont need to have two different datasources and delegate methods... You can just implement the methods an distinguish between the two using if condition...

Like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   if (tableView==tableView1){
      //then perform this 
}else{
//perform this.
}

}
```

you can similarly implement other delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

you may need two data sources and same delegates will operate for both in the controller but you have to trace it by yourself that the delegate is called for which of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Since every dataSource and delegate's function has  parameter tableView,
you could use it to distinguish each other.
But if you use two dataSource and delegate, there will less "if....else..." code.

Comment: How to implement two different sets of datasource and delegate in a single UIViewController ?

Comment: self.tableView1.delegate = self;
self.tableview2.delegate = self;

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
   if (tableView == self.tableView1)
   {
     //here is your first delegate code.
   }
   else if (tableView == self.tableView2)
   {
       //here is your second delegate code.
   }

}